# Can I share env variables between a job and a service in a github action?

Tags: github-actions

I am writing tests that connect to a database. To launch them in the CI on Github I use a service that deploys a postgres container. I need to pass the database connection details to this service (dbuser, dbname, and password). So, as shown in the [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers#running-jobs-in-containers), I have a snippet of yaml that looks like this:

```yaml
services:
      postgres:
        env:
          POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
          POSTGRES_USER: "myuser"
          POSTGRES_DBNAME: "mydbname"
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
```

This data must also be passed to my test code, so in my test job section there is something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    env:
      POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_USER: "myuser"
      POSTGRES_DBNAME: "mydbname"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
```

Put together:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    env:
      POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_USER: "myuser"
      POSTGRES_DBNAME: "mydbname"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
    steps:
      - ...
      - name: Run Tests
        run: run_my_tests
    services:
      postgres:
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        env:
          POSTGRES_PORT: "5432"
          POSTGRES_USER: "myuser"
          POSTGRES_DBNAME: "mydbname"
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
        image: postgres
```

Is there a way to avoid duplicating the connection data between the service and the build job ?

Comment: note: using ${{ env }} or yaml anchors does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should use secrets for all of that information and then everywhere you need it reference the secret within your file. It will still be duplicated but you’ll only need to set the values once.